# Suggestion PATH when entering file location in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to enter location of file in bash, like this :

```
while [[ ! -f "$location" ]]; do
   read -p "Enter application location : " location
done
```

Can I use **TAB** to autofill location like enter path in terminal. Can it done? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `-e` switch:

```
while [[ ! -f "$location" ]]; do
   read -ep "Enter application location >>> " location
done
```